# How do I copy from the build output directory to my server in a TFS build?

Tags: asp.net, tfs, webdeploy

I have a build definition set up on my TFS server. It builds happily but I can't figure out how to automate the process of having it copy the build to my development server.

I have a "Copy Files" task set up which works, but only when the source is this:

"C:\vsts-agent-win7-x64-2.103.1_work\8\s\ProjectName"

Obviously thats a hard-coded path and not great, so, is there an equivalent I could use to copy this build output to my development server?

Also, is there a way to have this happen over web deploy instead of file copy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the build variable *$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\ProjectName*, which should correspond to that folder. There is a link titled ["Pre-defined variables"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch) on the variables tab of your build definition that will show you other built-in variables.